# CSS For Displaying Two Things Side By Side

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I have the following code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');
.square {
  max-width: 460px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.square:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square .square-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

.square .square-details {
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}

.h11 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p0 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'merriweather';
}

.button56:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  color: white;
}

.square1:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square1 .square-image1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

.square1 .square-details1 {
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}

.square1 {
  max-width: 460px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  /*Removed the 10% margin*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .square1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 54px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .square1 .square-image1 img {
    height: 230px !important;
    border: 5px solid #555;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

.iframe {
  height: 1070px;
}

.container {
  --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / 2);
  padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / 2);
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="section-title">
    <h2>Featured Blogs Of The Day</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="square">
      <div class="square-image">
        <img src="assets/img/Blog1.png">
      </div>

      <div class="square-details">
        <h3 class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</h3>
        <p0>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p0>
        <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/chances-of-my-uni-college-admission-20bc0efec0af" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="square1">
      <div class="square-image1">
        <img src="assets/img/Blog2.png">
      </div>

      <div class="square-details1">
        <h3 class="h11">My Career Advice To You: Take These Steps...</h3>
        <p0>Humans tend to make mistakes — and its completely normal as it results in the growth and development of an individual — either psychologically or physically.</p0>
        <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/my-career-advice-to-you-take-these-steps-to-ultimate-prosperity-6c0687ce9c9f" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section id="resume" class="resume">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="section-title">
      <h2>IFrame
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="resume-item">
      <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/11nfRuy7JVyGX8LY2q9HR5JSqrBpFNtJ4/preview" width="100%" class="iframe"></iframe>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

So I just want the two blog cards displayed side by side, and not just side by side, but the corners should also match the corners of the iframe.

### Expected Output

[image]

See how the corners circled in orange are aligned with the iframe's corners?

I would like that.

**The first blog card already accomplishes that and there should be no changes made to the very first bog card. However, the blog card under it should be displayed next to it, with some margin in between, and have the corners aligned with the iframe.**

Any Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: use flex-box? put two sections in container and "display: flex; justify-content: center;" in container?

Comment: I tried but it did not work, but maybe I was doing it wrong. Are you able to show me?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: flex` in your container and have space between using `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');
.square {
  max-width: 460px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.square:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square .square-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

.square .square-details {
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}

.h11 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p0 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'merriweather';
}

.button56:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  color: white;
}

.square1:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square1 .square-image1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

.square1 .square-details1 {
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}

.square1 {
  max-width: 460px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  /*Removed the 10% margin*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .square1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 54px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .square1 .square-image1 img {
    height: 230px !important;
    border: 5px solid #555;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

.iframe {
  height: 1070px;
}

.container {
  --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / 2);
  padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / 2);
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="section-title">
    <h2>Featured Blogs Of The Day</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
    <div class="square">
      <div class="square-image">
        <img src="assets/img/Blog1.png">
      </div>

      <div class="square-details">
        <h3 class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</h3>
        <p0>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p0>
        <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/chances-of-my-uni-college-admission-20bc0efec0af" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="square1">
      <div class="square-image1">
        <img src="assets/img/Blog2.png">
      </div>

      <div class="square-details1">
        <h3 class="h11">My Career Advice To You: Take These Steps...</h3>
        <p0>Humans tend to make mistakes — and its completely normal as it results in the growth and development of an individual — either psychologically or physically.</p0>
        <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/my-career-advice-to-you-take-these-steps-to-ultimate-prosperity-6c0687ce9c9f" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section id="resume" class="resume">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="section-title">
      <h2>IFrame
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="resume-item">
      <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/11nfRuy7JVyGX8LY2q9HR5JSqrBpFNtJ4/preview" width="100%" class="iframe"></iframe>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
</div>
```